# Convert Json to JS Object with Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, javascript-objects

I have some excel files. I want to convert them to JS Objects. I can convert as Json like below.

```
{ "profileMenu.info": "Profile information",
        "profileMenu.infos.generalInfo": "general information",
        "profileMenu.infos.otherInfos": "Other information" }
```

I need to convert them like this.

```
  profileMenu: {
    info: 'Profile information',
    infos: {
      generalInfo: 'general information',
      otherInfos: 'Other information',
    }
```

I have searched for ways to do this but couldn't find any. Can you please help me on how to convert this Json to JS Objects?

Comment: `{ profileMenu.info: "Информация о профиле",` that is no valid JSON. In JSON keys have to be enclosed in double-quotes. Besides that, if you have something as `JSON`  encoded string, you can just copy and past it into JS code and use it as a JavaScript Object. Data encoded as JSON is a valid representation of a JavaScript Object in JS code.

Comment: Hmm, what does the JSO in JSON stand for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a nested object structure by string key/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791385/generate-a-nested-object-structure-by-string-key-path)

Comment: @t.niese You're right I have double-quotes in Json keys. I editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using external libraries,

In javascript, you can do this with [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```js
var myJSON = {
  "profileMenu.info": "Profile information",
  "profileMenu.infos.generalInfo": "general information",
  "profileMenu.infos.otherInfos": "Other information"
}

let myObject = {}

for (key in myJSON) {
  _.set(myObject, key, myJSON[key]);
}

console.log(myObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In Python, you can do this with [pydash](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
import pydash

myJSON = {
  "profileMenu.info": "Profile information",
  "profileMenu.infos.generalInfo": "general information",
  "profileMenu.infos.otherInfos": "Other information"
}

myObject = {}

for key in myJSON:
  pydash.set_(myObject, key, myJSON[key])
  
print(myObject)
```